# Swift: prepareForSegue not displaying data in next viewController

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pfquery

I'm trying a `prepareForSegue` method from my MainTableViewController (using PFQueryTableViewController) to my CommentsViewController, however, it doesn't display the data when I run my app. I want to be able to see the data at the top of the CommentsViewController and also have the relationship with the reply function in that same viewController. Basically, I want the blog post to be segued to the next page, so users comment on that specific post.

Here is my MainTableViewController(note: this isn't my whole file, just part of it):

```
    class MainTableViewController: PFQueryTableViewController

var blog:NSMutableArray! = NSMutableArray()
        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, object: PFObject!) -> PFTableViewCell? {
       let cell = tableView!.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("BLCell", forIndexPath: indexPath!) as! Blog


        if let userBlog : PFObject = self.blog.objectAtIndex(indexPath!.row) as! PFObject {

        cell.writer.text = object["author"] as? String
        cell.post.text = object["blog"] as? String
        let dateUpdated = object.createdAt! as NSDate
        let dateFormat = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormat.dateFormat = "h:mm a" 
        cell.dateTime.text =  NSString(format: "%@", dateFormat.stringFromDate(dateUpdated)) as String
       }         
        return cell
    }

       override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
            if(segue.identifier == "blogDetail"){
                let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
                let obj = self.objects[indexPath!.row] as! PFObject
                let navVC = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController
                let commentVC = navVC.topViewController as! CommentsViewController
                commentVC.blog = obj
            }
        }
```

Here is my CommentsViewController:

```
    class DetailViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
var blog: PFObject?
var comments: String?()
func replyButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject!) {
   blog?.addObject(commentField?.text, forKey: "comments")
        blog?.saveInBackground()
        if let tmpText = commentField?.text {
            comments?.append(tmpText)
        }
        commentField?.text = ""
        print(comments?.count)
        self.commentField?.resignFirstResponder()
        self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: What debugging have you already done on this code?

Comment: I tried creating a manualSegue method before. It displayed the data on the next page, however, it does not create a relationship between the blog and the comments. So I'm trying this method now above to create the relation and also have the blog appear on the next page

Comment: Try adding a break point at the beginning of the prepareForSegue and stepping over each line, checking it is getting a value.